# Stop Angular from removing canvas for Phaser game

Tags: angularjs, canvas, phaser-framework

In Angular we add different phaser.io games. During reorientation, Angular removes the canvas element, and the game vanishes.

A solution to this would be stopping Angular from removing the canvas element. Is this possible?

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: In other words, what have you tried so far? Code is beneficial.

Comment: Angular doesn't just blindly remove elements from the DOM without reason.  Without any code, it isn't possible to know what that reason might be in your situation.  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, #1.  "1.Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself."